# Defining an equation outside of function

Tags: java, function, variables, 3d, java-8

**Hello**

I am working on a `3d Grapher` and it works great!
and it works like this `y = f(x,z)`. y is upwards

so now I need to *set u with the variables x & z* in the function.

```
x & z are for loops
```

I want to have me executing the function and to set y *outside of the function*.
so I want need to enter the function everytime (planning to release as api)..

Is there someway of doing so?

Remember that i need to use the x and the z for Defining Y

Code (bit):

```
 public void ThreeDimensionalGraph(Location loc, double startX, double startZ, double endX, double endZ, double smoothness) {
                for (double x = startX; x < endX; x += smoothness) {
                    for (double z = startZ; z < endZ; z += smoothness) {
                        double y = x * z //i need to be able to use x and z;
                        //drawing
                    }
                }
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [DoubleBinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleBinaryOperator.html)

Your method would then look like this:

```
public void ThreeDimensionalGraph(Location loc, 
               double startX, double startZ, 
               double endX, double endZ, 
               double smoothness,
               DoubleBinaryOperator f) {
    for (double x = startX; x < endX; x += smoothness) {
        for (double z = startZ; z < endZ; z += smoothness) {
            double y = f.applyAsDouble(x, z);
            //drawing
        }
    }
}
```

And you can call it like

```
ThreeDimensionalGraph(loc, startX, startZ, endX, endZ, smoothness, (x,z) -> x*z);
ThreeDimensionalGraph(loc, startX, startZ, endX, endZ, smoothness, (x,z) -> Math.cos(x)*Math.cos(z));
```